# How to get event args values from contracts::contractemitted data?

Tags: polkadot-js

I am using

```
const decodedEvent = Abi.decodeEvent(Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from("00000064a7b3b6e00d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 'hex'))) 
(00000064a7b3b6e00d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is the data in the contracts::contractemitted event.)
```

But I cannot access the actual argument values, only their types. I'd like to be able to access the values when decoding the event. What am I missing?

Here's the `decodedEvent.event.args`
[image]

Currently when accessing the decodedEvent.event.args, I only see the names and types. Where can I access the values?

Comment: Did you check the content of `decodedEvent.event.data`?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the values should be in `decodedEvent.args`.

Comment: it isn't there, could it be due to an incorrect abi?

Comment: Might be the case, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```typescript
if (result.status.isInBlock) {

  result.events.forEach(({event, phase, topics}) => {

    if (api.events.contracts.ContractEmitted.is(event)) {

      const [account_id, contract_event] = event.data

      let decoded = new Abi(metadata).decodeEvent(contract_event)
      decoded = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(decoded));

      console.log(decoded)
    }
  });
}
```